# Table: a symbol instead of a vertical line

Tags: tables

I know it is a little unorthodox, but it would save me quite some time if I would be able to print a character instead of a vertical line in a table:

| a | b | c |   ->    | a | b $\sim$ c |

any clues?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the column separator `@{}`:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l@{$\rightarrow$}l|l@{${}\sim{}$}l|}
```

Here a complete minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l@{${}\rightarrow{}$}l|l@{${}\sim{}$}l|}
 a & b &c & a &  b & c \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also the documentation of [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array).

Comment: I've added the missing backslash, but also two empty items for getting the spacing right.

Comment: `array` package is not necessary

Comment: @LeoLiu: Indeed.